# C++ Array pointer-to-object error

Tags: c++

I am having what seems to be a common issue however reading through the replies to the similar questions I can't find the solution to my issue at all as I have already done what they are suggesting such as making the variable an array. I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

string eng2Str[4] = { "money", "politics", "RT", "#"};
int resArr[4];

int main()
{

    engine2(eng2Str[4], resArr[4]);

    system("Pause");
    system("cls");

    return 0;
}

void engine2(string &eng2Str, int &resArr)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sampleTweets.csv");
    int fcount = 0;
    string line;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        while (getline(fin, line)) {
            if (line.find(eng2Str[i]) != string::npos) {
                ++fcount;
            }
        }
        resArr[i] = fcount;
    }

    fin.close();

    return;
}
```

Before you mark as duplicate I have made sure of the following:

- The array and variable I am trying to assign are both int
- Its an array

The error is:

> expression must have pointer-to-object type

The error is occurring at the "resArr[i] = fcount;" line and am not sure why as resArr is an int array and I am trying to assign it a value from another int variable. I am quite new to C++ so any help would be great as I am really stuck!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you really mean to put a loop within a loop?

Comment: you have to paste the exact error message

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: Yes I did mean to put a loop within a loop as I need it to run through the file searching for several different keywords counting how many times they are used one after another. I have updated the original code with everything I have.

Comment: Declaring array as dimension 4 means the valid indices are 0 through 3.  So when you later write `eng2Str[4]` as function argument, you are accessing out of bounds. (Same with `resArr[4]`)

Comment: It seems like you want to pass the whole array to the function, but you wrote the function to pass just one string and one int

Comment: Okay so if I want to pass the entire array how would I go about that? I tried just putting eng2Str[] but that didnt work along with eng2Str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared your function to take a reference to a single `string` and `int`, not arrays. It should be:

```
void engine2(string *eng2Str, int *resArr)
```

or:

```
void engine2(string eng2Str[], int resArr[])
```

Then when you call it, you can give the array names as arguments:

```
engine2(eng2Str, resArr);
```

Another problem is the `while` loop in the function. This will read the entire file during the first iteration of the `for()` loop. Other iterations will not have anything to read, since it will be at the end of the file already. You could seek back to the beginning of the file, but a better way would be to rearrange the two loops so you just need to read the file once.

```
while (getline(fin, line)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (line.find(eng2Str[i]) != string::npos) {
            resArr[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The change in the loop has me a bit confused. Am I correct in saying that it will still run through the entire file 4 times searching for each of the 4 strings within the eng2str array and increasing the corresponding resArr value for each time is it found?

Comment: No. It goes through the file 1 time, and on each line it searches for 4 strings.

Comment: O god that is far more efficient... you sir are amazing thank you!

Comment: I am trying to do something similar in a different function where I am searching a file for specific words but need to return each line that it is found in. I am thinking I am going to need a multi-dimensional array with the first being the keyword that was searched and the second being the result but I can't get my head around how this would work. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: @KaiJones Use `std:map<std::string, int>`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of pure C array.
In your code, there are more issues. 
You are passing the fourth element of both arrays to the engine2 function.
From your definition of `void engine2(string &eng2Str, int &resArr)` you expect reference to a string (not array / vector) and an address / reference of int - you need to pass an pointer to the first element of resArr.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

vector<string> eng2Str = { "money", "politics", "RT", "#" };
int resArr[4] = {};

void engine2(const vector<string>& eng2Str, int* resArr)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sampleTweets.csv");
    int fcount = 0;
    string line;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        while (getline(fin, line)) 
        {
            if (line.find(eng2Str[i]) != string::npos)
            {
                ++fcount;
            }
        }
        resArr[i] = fcount;
    }

    fin.close();

    return;
}

int main()
{

    engine2(eng2Str, resArr);

    system("Pause");
    system("cls");

    return 0;
}
```